# Calculate centroid of a point cluster

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geometry, spatial-database

Having this function that inserts locations in a database:

```
def insertLocation(cur, label, point):
    print label
    cur.execute("""
            SELECT label, centroid, point_cluster
            FROM locations
            WHERE label=%s
            """, (label, ))
    if cur.rowcount > 0:
        # Updates current location set of points and centroid
        _, centroid, point_cluster = cur.fetchone()
        centroid = ppygis.Geometry.read_ewkb(centroid)
        point_cluster = ppygis.Geometry.read_ewkb(point_cluster)

################ problem here! ####################
        point_cluster = pointsFromDb(point_cluster)

        centroid = computeCentroid(point_cluster)


        #point_cluster.points.append(ppygis.Point(point.latitude, point.longitude, point.elevation, srid=4326))

        cur.execute("""
                UPDATE locations
                SET centroid=%s, point_cluster=%s
                WHERE label=%s
                """, (centroid.write_ewkb(), point_cluster.write_ewkb(), label))
```

As you can see what I'm trying to achieve with the `computeCentroid` function is that for a set of points that represent the same location I can have the approximate location by calculating a mean of that cluster. So, I tried to create that `computeCentroid` function:

```
def computeCentroid(points):
    xs = map(lambda p: p[0], points)
    ys = map(lambda p: p[1], points)
    centroid = [np.mean(xs), np.mean(ys)]
    return centroid
```

How can I process my point_cluster in order to use this centroid function? That point cluster is a collection of linestrings but I can't seem to access them in order to calculate the centroid.

I'm trying this function in order to transform the cluster to be used by the centroid function:

```
def pointsFromDb(gis_points):
    gis_points = ppygis.Geometry.read_ewkb(gis_points).points
    print gis_points
    result = []
    for i, point in enumerate(gis_points):
        result.append(ppygis.Point(point.x, point.y, p.elevation, srid=4326))
    return result
```

But it says:

```
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not LineString
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I really understand what you are doing.
How can a point cluster be a collection of linestrings?
, but ..

Remember you are using a spatial database, why not use the functionality in PostGIS?

from a bunch of points you can collect them and use ST_Centroid on the collection.

Or if it really is a collection of linestrings that you want to get the centroid from, use ST_Centroid on that collection.

And, don't take the result out of the database. Just update with it at once, and use it from there.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html